# How to use __uuidof in MINGW?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, com, mingw

I want to use __uuidof in function CoCreateInstance:

```
CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,__uuidof(Isesoft),(LPVOID*)&pem);
```

error:

```
'__uuidof' was not declared in this scope.
```

How can I use it in MINGW?

Comment: Isn't `__uuidof()` an extension of the MSVC compiler?

Comment: @g-makulik: Perhaps it is but the question how to live without it in mingw is a reasonable one.

Comment: A related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/84269/57428

Answer (score 3):

`__uuidof` is an MS specific extension, but you should be able to replace `__uuidof(IMyInterface)` with `IID_IMyInterface` for the same behavior in a portable way.

Comment: When I used IID_IMyInterface , the error is "IID_IMyInterface was not declared in this scope". The com component that I called is a third party soft.

Comment: @CodeCat are you pulling in the COM interface via an `#import` directive, perchance ? If not, from where did you get the `Isesoft` interface definition? Is it from an accompanying header file with your 3rd party COM lib ?

Comment: I used OLE VIEWER to get interface definition.And I have an header file with it(but the header file is not supplied by the com lib's vendor. I can't ensure it is complete right.

Comment: It sounds like you built you own header/idl file, so will need to include the GUID definition in you header (I'm assuming you have that from oleview). Can you add your file - especially the part where you include the interface GUID - to the question?